# extracting geneids from a sequence

Tags: string, r, dna-sequence

I have an object in R which saves a list of geneids and sequences.

```
$`140545`

[1] 

"GAAACATCCGAGGCTGGAGTGAGCCACGCGGAGGAGGAAGAACAGCCCGAGCTCACAGGGGCGGGGAAGAGTTCTAGCTCGCGACAGCCC"

$`57187`

[1] 

"CGGGCAGAGACGCTCCTCACTTTCCAGACTGGGCAGCCAGGCAGAGGGGCTCCTCACATCCCAGACGATGGGCGGCCAGGCAGAGAGGCTC"
```

I want to only store the ids in an object. e.g How will I achieve it in R

```
[1] 140545

[2] 57187
```

I am extremely new to R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ids <- names(your_list_object)
```

However, note that the ids will be saved as characters. So, if you want them numerically, you may have to use `ids <- as.numeric(names(your_list_object))`.

Also, R generally provides many easy ways to extract 'names' *attributes* from objects. For example look at ?names, ?rownames, ?colnames, ?dimnames etc.